# Is the computing power of the Raspberry Pi sufficient to run Google Docs, Youtube and maybe Team Fortress 2?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am curious about how powerful the Raspberry Pi is. For the price it is quite cheap. However I want to know if it is up to the task of:

- Basic email
- Google docs
- Youtube
- Running Steam (linux) on the default ARM linux installation.

Can someone who has the Rasp Pi comment?

Comment: **Its highly unlikely Steam runs on the ARM port of Linux.**  Its also unlikely that Raspberry Pi  has the graphical abilities to even run Team Fortress 2.

Comment: [R.pi questions are **on topic**](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5984/can-we-make-raspberry-pi-questions-off-topic-and-avoid-hurting-raspberry-pi-se) for [su]

Comment: put android on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic Email: Yes (though browser load is slow)

Google Docs: Yes (though browser load is slow)

Youtube: Kindof, but I wouldn't suggest it often

Any Actual Games: No, unless you can compile Steam from Source, I don't think it supports ARM.  Snake would work fine...

The Raspberry Pi isn't really fit for use as a computer for those used to decent performance, it's good for embedded/dedicated applications or to get low cost computers into cultures that cannot really afford computers.

The idea is to get a start of familiarity and some programming experience, very basic computer functions.  But just loading the web browser is fairly slow.

Edit 3/17/16:

After a few years and a few iterations, it has become more of a reasonable computer.  It can now run minecraft (skimmed down a little I believe) and a few other games and such much better, which has also brought up the performance of the other basic usage elements. I am not sure I would make it a primary computer, but it's definitely much better now than my original post.